# Changing screen capture saving folder

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to change screen capture saving folder. I am using phantomjs.
It saves screenshots in the same directory as phantomjs directory.
How can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indicate the desired folder to save a screenshot in the render method itself:

```
page.render('/path/to/file.png');
```